# I want to send a multi line otp sms through rawurlencode but its not working

Tags: php

I am using the following to try to send a multiline OTP sms through my php api using rawurlencode

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Smsmodel extends CI_Model {
    
/***************************************Send Sms OTP*******************************/

function smsotp($mobile,$otp)
    
    {
         $mobile_no=array($mobile);
    
    //  Account details
    $apiKey = urlencode('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
    // Message details
    $numbers = $mobile_no;
    $sender = urlencode('XXXXXX');
    $message = rawurlencode("Dear User,\nYour OTP for registering with XYZ is" .$otp.".\nOTPs are secret and should not be shared with anyone.\nRegards,\nTeam XYZ.");
    $numbers = implode(',', $numbers);
    // Prepare data for POST request
    $data = array('apikey' => $apiKey, 'numbers' => $numbers, "sender" => $sender, "message" => $message);
    // Send the POST request with cURL
    $ch = curl_init('https://api.textlocal.in/send/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    // Process your response here
//  echo($response);die;
    }

}
```

Its not working for some reason. What to do ?

Comment: _"not working"_ in what sense? What happens when you do what with it? Not sure if OTP has some different formatting, but normally a line break is `\n` and not `%n`

Comment: It doesn't send the sms. Invalid template error message. I am wondering if the above is the right way to send a multi line otp sms using rawurlencode or something wrong with my code ?

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't even try and send anything. It's just encoding a string with some concatenated variables. We don't know how you're actually sending it or what that service requires. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. You need to add _all_ relevant code together with the exact error message you get.

Comment: I have pasted the full code.

Comment: You should contact the API provider (the ones you're sending it to) and ask how to do it in their API. We aren't them so we can't answer what they need or how they want it. We can help you if you get stuck on your code, but not as a support for third party services.

Comment: Look at the code and tell me if it is okay ?

Comment: Why don't you use [their PHP class](https://api.textlocal.in/docs/phpclass) instead of doing it all manually? Less error prone.

Comment: I will try them in the meantime any way to fix my code if its not okay ?

Comment: I'll repeat it... We do not work at that company. If you get a specific error from their API and you don't understand it, _ask them_ what it means and how to solve it.

Comment: I have done that already. But as far as I understand my issue is in the line break. the message in the rawurlencode is not taking any line break for some reason.

Comment: Then you need to wait for them to come back with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to replace `%n` with `\n` (as Magnus mentioned in the comments).

That way, `rawurlencode` will encode it properly as `%0A`, which is the encoding for a new line in a URL.

Comment: From the API's documentation it says that invalid template means this - "Invalid Template. The message given didn't match any approved templates on your account." (https://api.textlocal.in/docs/sendsms)

Comment: That is the issue. My template is a multi line template and in rawurlencode i am using ' \n ' to put a line break, but its not working.

Comment: You should contact their support and ask. Did you try to get it to work first with a template that doesn't have multi-lines, and did it work? Maybe the template with the multi-line has extra space before the new line and it makes a difference. "Dear user,<space>". Or maybe you need to send it as "\r\n"... Or maybe the template exists but wasn't approved? many options for why it's not working.

Comment: My template with textlocal is like
Dear User,
Your OTP for registering with XYZ is 1234.
OTPs are secret are should not be shared with anyone.
Regards,
Team XYZ.